# How to get this value in a variable and use it in a conditional in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jsx

I would appreciate any help in getting this sorted out. In the code below I would like to take the values between `` from the span and assign them to a variable in order to have the following logic:

```
${research.data.codesRelated[1].code} === undefined 
  ? ${research.data.description} 
  : ${research.data.codesRelated[1].code} ${research.data.description}
```

How can I do this? It seems so easy but I couldn't sort it out, don't know where to place the const & conditional rendering inside the code and to make it work. Everyone in advance.

The code is below:

```
const Research: FC<ResearchProps> = memo(
  ({ research, hideLabel = false, intl }) => (
    <div className="section research">
       <div className="section__value" id="container-research-value">
        <div className="research-info">
          <div className="description" id="element-research-description">
            <PopoverWrapper
              id="element-research-description-tooltip"
              trigger="hover"
              placement="top"
              speaker={<span className="text-tooltip">{research.data.description}</span>}
            >
              **<span>{`${research.data.codesRelated[1].code} ${research.data.description}`}</span>**
            </PopoverWrapper>
          </div>
```

Comment: You *could* just put it there, although I wouldn't--better to pull out the string before the render.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```js
const Research: FC<ResearchProps> = memo(
  ({ research, hideLabel = false, intl }) => (
    <div className="section research">
       <div className="section__value" id="container-research-value">
        <div className="research-info">
          <div className="description" id="element-research-description">
            <PopoverWrapper
              id="element-research-description-tooltip"
              trigger="hover"
              placement="top"
              speaker={<span className="text-tooltip">{research.data.description}</span>}
            >
              <span>{research.data.codesRelated[1].code === undefined ?
                        research.data.description
                      : <>
                       {research.data.codesRelated[1].code} {research.data.description}
                      </>}
              </span>
            </PopoverWrapper>
          </div>
```

Comment: Your code snippet is failing to run, `Uncaught SyntaxError: Missing initializer in const declaration`

Answer (score 0):

As already was mentioned, you can use the ternary operator.

You can use a simple hack: conditional rendering for code with space at the end of the string template.

```
<span>
{research.data.codesRelated[1].code && `${research.data.codesRelated[1].code} `}
{`${research.data.description}`}
</span>
```

But the best way to create an external function for build this string. And your render will be like this:

```
<span>
{buildResearchDescription(research.data)}
</span>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it seems that is not validating if research.data.codesRelated[1].code === undefined

Comment: const research = {
  data: {
    description: "Some description",
    codesRelated: [{}, {}]
  },
}

With this data structure, it works properly.

Inside curly braces in jsx is just javascript code.